# Slice endpoints invisibly truncated

Tags: python, python-2.7, cpython

```
>>> class Potato(object):
...    def __getslice__(self, start, stop):
...       print start, stop
...         
>>> sys.maxint
9223372036854775807
>>> x = sys.maxint + 69
>>> print x
9223372036854775876
>>> Potato()[123:x]
123 9223372036854775807
```

Why the call to getslice doesn't respect the `stop` I sent in, instead silently substituting 2^63 - 1? Does it mean that implementing `__getslice__` for your own syntax will generally be unsafe with longs?

I can do whatever I need with `__getitem__` anyway, I'm just wondering why `__getslice__` is apparently broken.

**Edit:**  Where is the code in CPython which truncates the slice?  Is this part of python (language) spec or just a "feature" of cpython (implementation)?

Comment: Has to be said: "why yes, I would like 2^64 slices of this fine potato". Seriously though, I really wish I had an answer

Comment: It's one slice .. and it would happen the same with a smaller slice like `maxint-2:maxint+2`  :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Python C code that handles slicing *for objects that implement the `sq_slice` slot*, cannot handle any integers over `Py_ssize_t` (== [`sys.maxsize`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.maxsize)). The `sq_slice` slot is the C-API equivalent of the `__getslice__` special method.

For a two-element slice, Python 2 uses one of the [`SLICE+*` opcodes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-SLICE+0); this is then handled by the [`apply_slice()` function](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/241f9aa9fb89/Python/ceval.c#l4396). This uses the [`_PyEval_SliceIndex` function](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/241f9aa9fb89/Python/ceval.c#l4354) to convert the Python index objects (`int`, `long`, or anything implementing the [`__index__` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__index__)) to a `Py_ssize_t` integer. The method has the following comment:

```c
/* Extract a slice index from a PyInt or PyLong or an object with the
   nb_index slot defined, and store in *pi.
   Silently reduce values larger than PY_SSIZE_T_MAX to PY_SSIZE_T_MAX,
   and silently boost values less than -PY_SSIZE_T_MAX-1 to -PY_SSIZE_T_MAX-1.
   Return 0 on error, 1 on success.
*/
```

This means that *any* slicing in Python 2 using the 2-value syntax is limited to values in the `sys.maxsize` range when a `sq_slice` slot is provided.

Slicing using the three-value form (`item[start:stop:stride]`) uses the [`BUILD_SLICE` opcode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-BUILD_SLICE) instead (followed by [`BINARY_SUBSCR`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-BINARY_SUBSCR)) and this instead creates a [`slice()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice) without limiting to `sys.maxsize`.

If the object doesn't implement a `sq_slice()` slot (so no `__getslice__` is present) the `apply_slice()` function also falls back to using a `slice()` object.

As for this being an implementation detail or part of the language: the [*Slicings* expression documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#slicings) distinguishes between `simple_slicing` and `extended_slicing`; the former only permits the `short_slice` form. For simple slicing the indices must be *plain integers*:

> The lower and upper bound expressions, if present, must evaluate to plain integers; defaults are zero and the `sys.maxint`, respectively.

This *suggests* that Python 2 *the language* limits the indices to `sys.maxint` values, disallowing long integers. In Python 3 simple slicing has been excised from the language altogether.

If your code has to support slicing with values beyond `sys.maxsize` *and* you have to inherit from a type that implements `__getslice__` then your options are to:

- use the three-value syntax, with `None` for the stride:

  ```
  Potato()[123:x:None]
  ```
- to create `slice()` objects explicitly:

  ```
  Potato()[slice(123, x)]
  ```

`slice()` objects can handle `long` integers just fine; however the [`slice.indices()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#slice.indices) cannot handle lengths over `sys.maxsize` still:

```
>>> import sys
>>> s = slice(0, sys.maxsize + 1)
>>> s
slice(0, 9223372036854775808L, None)
>>> s.stop
9223372036854775808L
>>> s.indices(sys.maxsize + 2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: cannot fit 'long' into an index-sized integer
```

Comment: Thanks.  Can you comment on whether this is language or implementation?

Comment: @wim: The line is blurred here; I'd say this is an implementation limit.

Comment: @wim: updated to quote the documentation on this; it looks to be a language issue here, not an implementation detail.