# Partial inheritance - inheriting some functionality, minus a problematic method

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, monkeypatching

When inheriting from a parent which has implemented the deprecated `__getslice__`, is there any way to get at the original slice before it gets munged?

Here is the example test case, I don't know how to override `__getslice__` at a point before the relevant information is already lost.  Can it be done instead with monkeypatching?  Can it be done via cpython extension?

```
from unittest import TestCase
from mock import patch
import sys


class BigIntSlicableList(list):
    def __getslice__(self, start, stop):
        return self[start:stop:None]  # force fallback to __getitem__ 


class BigIntSlicableListTest(TestCase):

    @patch.object(BigIntSlicableList, '__getitem__')
    def test_slice_big_endpoint(self, mock):
        mylist = BigIntSlicableList([1, 2, 3])
        start, stop = sys.maxint - 1, sys.maxint + 1
        bigint_slice = slice(start, stop)
        mylist[start:stop]
        mock.assert_called_once_with(bigint_slice)
        self.assertEqual(mylist[start:stop], mylist[start:stop:])
```

*Note*: I just use `list` here as an [ssce](http://sscce.org/), I'm not really trying to make a BigList class but wondering how to get around the limitation when a parent class may have already implemented `__getslice__`.

The following attempt doesn't work:

```
class MyList(list):
    pass

del MyList.__getslice__
```

The del statement raises `AttributeError`, even though `hasattr(MyList, '__getslice__')` returns True.

This question follows on from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25597815/674039).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, not with a monkeypatch on a type defined in C. That's because `list` doesn't have a `__getslice__`. It instead fills the `sq_slice` slot in the [`PySequenceMethods` structure](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/typeobj.html#PySequenceMethods). Overriding is allowed, but you cannot make it go away.

Even if you inherited from a Python implementation, monkey patching would come down to *deleting the `__getslice__` method* from the original class.

Your only option is to provide your own version, and that includes the `sys.maxsize` limitations. I prefer using a [`slice()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice) for such an override:

```
def __getslice__(self, start, stop):
    return self[slice(start, stop)]
```

provided the base type knows how to handle a `slice` object (which it has to do if it wanted to support strides).

You can avoid the `__getslice__` method altogether by using the three-element slice notation or by passing in an explicit `slice()` object:

```
mylist[start:stop:None]
mylist[slice(start, stop)]
```

Comment: Can you somehow remove `__getslice__` from the MRO?

Comment: Is the override in your example behaving identically to the override I showed in the question?  Why is it preferable?

Comment: @wim: no, you cannot. There is no way to pretend the method isn't there.

Comment: @wim: I prefer creating a `slice()` object rather than have Python do it; under the hood `self[start:stop:None]` creates that object *anyway*.

Comment: @wim: I posted an answer on your previous question as well; you cannot work around this by 'deleting' the `__getslice__` in any case.